# Compiler failure when compiling SciPy with MinGW+GCC

Tags: python, gcc, assembly, compiler-errors, mingw32

I am running some python code where some code needs gcc compilation (dont ask me I dont have a clue). I was getting the error that gcc not recognised. I installed Mingw and gcc compiler, so that was sorted. But now the assembler is creating a very large file name and getting into error. see the error below:

Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create c:\users\kd1234\appdata\local\temp\scipy-as07487-7op0cx\python27_intermediate\compiler_6cb9c52cab22cd58c3b2a33f029b68476828f4189dc8dd305efd20ec06666d43\Release\users\as07487\appdata\local\temp\kd1234\python27_compiled\sc_ed5391b748bc47781f90305835197df10c5f33c0bbba9a3f5660ab3c277c2b50657.o: No such file or directory

I looked at it and it looks like this file name generated by the compiler is too large for windows thus cant create it and getting into error.Has anyone got some idea how to sort this one out!

Cheers

Comment: are you using native code? and it looks like its missing an object file.

Comment: It is assembler message, I think this is  a message related to a very large file name created by the compiler, thus it cant write to it

Comment: but it says no such file, so that means the file isn't getting made. unless it is poorly written compiler which gcc isn't, it shouldn't care about the string size

Comment: see in the error first line it says "can't create ". I nevigated to that directory to check. It is true that you cant create that large file name and path. I created a text file to test, and i cant name the text file with that name as the name becomes too big which may be a limitation in windows. Gcc does not take that into accout and I think that is the issue! You can test that by creating that large directory structure, and naming a file like that, windows wont let you. Is there any way i can go around that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path length is 290 characters, which does indeed exceed the limit of 260 characters imposed by most Windows APIs.

Part of the path bloat appears to be due to %TEMP%; try setting %TEMP% to C:\ before running the script and see if that makes it work.

Comment: That is brilliant! you are a star nneonne, that solved the issue!. Not sure why people always keep disliking my posts. It was easily understandable and you solved it in a tick :) I would give you a thumb up as deserved but i cant reach to 15 reputation to do so as people keep disliking lol. One day i will reach 15 likes!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answered your question, please *accept* it by ticking the green checkmark. Thanks!